# Using Google Places Search without violating terms

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

As the title says, my app takes parameters from the user and displays relevant locations around them. But from what I understand, the Google Maps API terms prohibit you from doing this. Can this use be termed as a listing service, where I'm simply displaying the data I got from Google. I'm also providing all relevant attributions.

Comment: My understanding is that if you render the actual locations on a Google Map, you would not be in violation of the service.  Are you not using a map with your application?

Comment: The app maintains a bunch of place ids (acquired from Google itself) that it must display in a list. Can this be considered a listing service when I'm only displaying 8-10 places at any given time?

Also, can you tell me more about how displaying these places on a map wouldn't be a violation? Thanks for your answer

Comment: [See here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies).  You can geocode so long as you display a map to your users.

Comment: I think geocoding is not what I need. I need results from Google Places Search which I'm going to display as is but in a list in my app. I can provide attributions and set it up so that clicking on a place opens it up in the Google maps app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding